# where() showing "IS NULL" instead of variable value in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$email='abc@abc.com';
$pass= 123;
$this->db->select('*')->from('user')->where('email',$email)->where('password',$pass)-> get()->result();
```

this gives result :-

```
'select * from user where email IS NULL and password IS NULL';
```

But it works with `$this->db->query();`

plz help me to find why its not taking like :-

```
'select * from user where email="abc@abc.com" and password="123" ';
```

Comment: this should work as expected... whats your CI version ?`

Comment: @sintakonte  its 3.1.6

Comment: @KiranTrimbake check my anwer below.

Comment: what do you get if you try `echo $this->db->select('*')->from('user')->where('email',$email)->where('password',$pass)->get_compiled_select();`

Comment: @sintakonte  Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::get_compiled_select()

Comment: $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='".$email."' AND `password`='".$pass."'");return $query->result();          this way its working but not with active records why?

Comment: dude i've no idea but i think there is something seriously wrong here... pls post your database.php (without credentials ofc) and how you load this db ... and show your model too

Answer (score -1):

Use this method. Hope it will help you

```
$email = "abc@example.com"; 
$password = "abc123";

public function getdata()
{
    // first load your model if not added in your config/autoload file
    return $this->db->get_where('table_name', array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password))->row_array();

}
```